# C++ Read a file and store it into a string

Tags: c++, string, filestream

For part of a C++ project I need to store all the words from a list in a .txt document into a string. The .txt document is formatted like this:

Word1
Word2
Word3
Word4

I can open the file with no problem, but I'm struggling to save all the words in the file to a string. Would someone be able to help me get started?

Comment: How are you opening the file? please post your code.

Comment: Do you want to store the whole file into a single string, or have a separate string for each word?

Comment: I want to store the whole file into a single string.

Comment: Consider `s.append(istream_iterator<char>(ifile), {});`. If you want space-separated, use `noskipws(ifile);` before appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what process are you using to get input from the file. So I am going to describe the easiest. [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/) . To open a file using freopen you just type

```
freopen("a.txt","r",stdin);
```

at the begining of the main function. Every thing after this would be like you are taking input from console.
Now about your string. I don't know if you want to save the words in a space separated string or not, I assume you want that. Here is an example code

```
string main_string;
string temporary_string; // word read in each attempt;
while(cin>>temporary_string)
{
   main_string = main_string +" "+temporary_string;

}
```

this code will read until the end of file. You can also use the [append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) function

Comment: How exactly does freopen work? What do each parts of it do?

Comment: The first parameter is the path of the file you want to read text from, the second parameter is the mode the file will open , and the third is the FILE stream that is bounded. cin,scanf is the standard input , so after freopen when ever you will specify cin or scanf , the input will be taken from the file instead of console.

Comment: you can mark the ans as accepted